# Fill input value with ajax (Laravel6)

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have a problem concerning the filling of Input after selection in a Dropdown.
I have a table in my database with contact details.
On my form, I have a Dropdown which displays the names of people, and which, once I click on the name, fills in the fields with the data.
To do this, I use Ajax with Jquery, my request is well treated with a response but nothing appears in my fields. How to solve this problem ?

The dropdown :

```
       <select class="form-control select2 col-md-7" id="selInscrit" name="selInscrit">
            @foreach($inscrit as $inscrits)
            <option value="{{$inscrits->INS_ID}}">{{$inscrits->INS_CIVILITE}} {{$inscrits->INS_NOM}} {{$inscrits->INS_PREN}} {{$inscrits->INS_NUM_RUE}} {{$inscrits->INS_Rue}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

The form :

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label for="INS_CIVILITE">Civilité</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_CIVILITE" name="INS_CIVILITE">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1">Mme</option>
                <option value="2">Mlle</option>
                <option value="3">M.</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="INS_NOM">Nom</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_NOM" name="INS_NOM" value=""  type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="INS_PREN">Prénom</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_PREN" name="INS_PREN" value=""  type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_NAISS">Année Naiss</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_NAISS" name="INS_NAISS" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_AGE">Age</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_AGE" name="INS_AGE" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label for="INS_NUM_RUE"># Rue</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_NUM_RUE" name="INS_NUM_RUE" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <label for="INS_Rue">Libellé voie</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_Rue" name="INS_Rue" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_TEL1">Téléphone 1</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_TEL1" name="INS_TEL1" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <label for="INS_OBS">Observation</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_OBS" name="INS_OBS" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_DATE">Date d'inscription</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_DATE" name="INS_DATE" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_TEL2">Téléphone 2</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_TEL2" name="INS_TEL2" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The script for Ajax :

```
<script>
$('#selInscrit').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = '{{ route("show", ":id") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', id);

    $.ajax({

        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != null) {
                $('#INS_CIVILITE').val(response.INS_CIVILITE);
                $('#INS_NOM').val(response.INS_NOM);
                $('#INS_PREN').val(response.INS_PREN);
                $('#INS_NAISS').val(response.INS_NAISS);
                $('#INS_AGE').val(response.INS_AGE);
                $('#INS_NUM_RUE').val(response.INS_NUM_RUE);
                $('#INS_Rue').val(response.INS_Rue);
                $('#INS_TEL1').val(response.INS_TEL1);
                $('#INS_OBS').val(response.INS_OBS);
                $('#INS_DATE').val(response.INS_DATE);
                $('#INS_TEL2').val(response.INS_TEL2);
            }

        }

    });
});
```

The controller :

```
public function show($id = 0)
{
    $data = Inscrit::where('INS_ID', $id)->first();
    dd($id, $data);
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

The database
[image]

The form
[image]

The response
[image]

Comment: did you tried to console.log(response) ?

Comment: After the script ? response is not defined.

Comment: When you dd something it renders that object to the output, which means it will corrup the json response. Please take it out and inspect the ajax response like Roued says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should remove the `dd($id, $data)` because The dd function dumps the given variables and ends execution of the script

Something like

```
success: function (data) {
    if(data === undefined) {
        alert('empty');
        return;
    }
    $('#INS_CIVILITE').val(response.INS_CIVILITE);
    $('#INS_NOM').val(response.INS_NOM);
    $('#INS_PREN').val(response.INS_PREN);
    //...
}
```

should work.

Comment: You would like to re populate the select or just set selected option ??

Comment: Populate the select, but it's ok, I just change de value of each one (for example, 3 to M.) and it works.